# How to receive an Image as response via xhr?

Tags: image, dojo, xmlhttprequest

How to receive an Image via `dojo.xhr`?

I have a `datagrid`, and on clicking on any row,
I want to get an image (which depends on the row selected)from the server. The image is to be popped as a dialog.

I don't see any `handleAs` parameter approprite for this.

Currently I have two options,

1) Define an `<image>` inside the dialog, `onClick` event shows the dialog as well as set the `src` parameter to the server image returning link(This doesn't look asynchronous).

2) Encode the image using `Base64`, pass as json.(And what? how to convert it back to image at the browser?)

I am not satisfied with any of the above.

Please suggest. Thanks.

**EDIT**

2) Contd. found a way to get this working by setting `src="data:image/jpeg; base64, *deferredObj*"` attribute of the `<image>` tag, but still to me, it isn't an obvious way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your thoughts and your time. I have realized that XHR is not designed for binary data (like images)
I have changed design of my application accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use base64 encoding of image. IE has a poor support of `data:image`.

Image URL is the correct way to go. The solution 1) is better. If the performance is not good,  use [image preloading](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317) to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw with `IE` and `data:image`. I am concentrating on `FF` only. But both the approaches are un-obvious to me. I feel that there are neater ways of doing it, eg something like setting mimetype `Content-Type = image/jpg`. `Http`-`Mimetypes` are there for like 15 years for this purpose. I mean sending images via `xhr` is fairly a trivial task, and I can't believe it can't be done with `dojo`(in the standard or at least simple ways) :(

Answer (score 0):

When you're building your grid structure, include a `formatter: myFunction`attribute.  Then use `myFunction`to call dojo.xhrGet to get the image.  So, something like this:

```
grid = new dojox.grid.dataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        structure: gridStructure
});
gridStructure = [
    {field: 'id', name: 'ID', formatter: myFunction}
];
myFunction = function(){
    dojo.xhrGet(
        //retrieve image here   
    );
}
```